# Binary search tree with strings

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have a book that explains the theory behind binary search tree in a very bad way i know that there is something about the order of both left and right child but i still cannot get the idea about one being greater than the other previous level.

Take for example this tree of strings:

[image: Binary tree of names]

(sorry for my paint) this example is taken directly from my book :)

Could someone explain the order to me ? what is the logic behind this?

Comment: If there really are two `Karen` nodes in the example tree, then it is technically not a BST, because duplicate nodes are not allowed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a BST every node has at most a left child and a right child. Every node on the left of a given node is smaller than it, and every node on the right of a given node is greater than it. One of the consequences of this is that you can't have duplicate values, so I'm not sure if that example is exactly how the book has it.

In the example you have, the strings are ordered alphabetically. Taking the root node as an example, Bob comes before Karen, so Bob goes on Karen's left. Tom comes after Karen, so Tom goes on Karen's right. Looking at the tree as a whole, you can see that every node on Karen's left (Bob, Alan, Ellen) comes before Karen alphabetically and every node on Karen's right (Tom, Wendy) comes after Karen alphabetically. This pattern is the same no matter which node you look at.

Comment: 'Smaller than' in this case means 'alphabetically before'.

Comment: See my comment on @irrelephant's answer.  It is not sufficient that every node's left is < parent, and every node's right is > parent to define a BST.  Your third sentence does not necessarily follow from the second and first without defining every node's left/right *subtree* as being less/greater than the parent.

Comment: Fair enough, I should have explained in more detail. I'll update.

Comment: 'Smaller than' can also be referred to as a 'lexicographical comparison' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order

Answer (score 2):

For any node (Karen - the root - for example), *every* node in the left subtree (Bob, Alan, Ellen) is lexicographically smaller than Karen, and every node in the right subtree (Tom, Wendy) is larger than Karen.

The 2nd Karen shouldn't be there, as @mellamokb points out in the comments.

As such, you can binary search this tree in O(log N) time as you would a sorted array.

Comment: The second does not necessarily follow from the first.  For instance, if the root was `Karen`, then left from `Karen` was `Bob`, then right from `Bob` was `Tom`, it would satisfy your first condition, but not the second.  It is necessary that a BST be *defined* as having all nodes in the left/right *subtree* being less/greater than the parent node.

Answer (score 1):

In the Binary search tree implementation for strings, the strings are stored in lexicographical order. For instance, if there are three alphabets ('K', 'I', and 'N') that are stored in different string data types and are inserted in the same order, then 'K' will be the parent node with 'I' as its left child and 'N' as its right child because 'I' comes before 'K' and 'N' comes after 'K' in alphabetical order (Figure: 1). Same goes for the words: "Linked" will be stored as the left child of "List" or "List" will be stored as the right child of "Linked" depending on the order we are inserting them into the tree.

**Implementation in C# for better understanding**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BSTString
{
    public class BinaryStringSearchTree
    {
        // Private class so that it cannot be accessed outside of parent class
        private class Node
    {
        // Data field of the node 
        public string _data;

        // Stores address of left child
        public Node _leftNode;

        // Stores address of right child
        public Node _rightNode;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data"></param>
        public Node(string data)
        {
            this._data = data;          // String is stored in the data field of the node
            this._rightNode = this._leftNode = null;    // Right and left child are set to null
        }
    }

    // Stores the root of the tree
    private Node root;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor 
    /// Root is set as null
    /// </summary>
    public BinaryStringSearchTree()
    {
        root = null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param> // Value which is to be stored in root
    public BinaryStringSearchTree(string value)
    {
        // Creates a new node with value and stores into root
        root = new Node(value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Function to call insertString() function
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    public void insert(string data)
    {
        // Inserting data into tree
        root = insertString(root, data);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Private recursive function which is called to insert data into the tree
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="root"></param>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Node insertString(Node root, string data)
    {
        // Base Case: 
        // If the tree is empty
        if (root == null)
        {
            // Data is stored at root
            root = new Node(data);

            // root node is returned 
            return root;
        }

        /*
         * string.Compare(a, b) function will return 
         * 0 if a is equal to b
         * 1 if a is greater than b
         * -1 if a is smaller than b
         */

        // -- Recursively moving down the tree --
        // If data stored at root is greater then the data
        if (string.Compare(root._data, data) > 0)
        {
            root._leftNode = insertString(root._leftNode, data);
        }
        // If data stored at root is smaller then the data
        else if (string.Compare(root._data, data) < 0)
        {
            root._rightNode = insertString(root._rightNode, data);
        }

        return root;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Function to call deleteString() function
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    public void delete(string data)
    {
        root = deleteNode(root, data);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Private recursive function which is called to delete data from the tree
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="root"></param>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Node deleteNode(Node root, string data)
    {
        // Base case: 
        // If the tree is empty
        if (root == null)
        {
            return root;
        }

        // -- Recursively moving down the tree --
        // If data stored at root is greater then the data
        if (string.Compare(root._data, data) > 0)
        {
            root._leftNode = deleteNode(root._leftNode, data);
        }
        // If data stored at root is smaller then the data
        else if (string.Compare(root._data, data) < 0)
        {
            root._rightNode = deleteNode(root._rightNode, data);
        }
        // If data stored at root is same as the data
        else
        {
            // Base case 
            // If the node does not have right or left child 
            if (root._leftNode == null && root._rightNode == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            // Node with only one child
            if (root._rightNode == null)
            {
                return root._leftNode;
            }
            else if (root._leftNode == null)
            {
                return root._rightNode;
            }

            // Node which has two children 
            // Finds In-Order Sucessor - smallest in the right subtree
            Node inodrsuc = inOrderSucessor(root._rightNode);

            // Replacing the In-Order sucessor of root with data of root
            root._data = inodrsuc._data;

            // Delete the In-Order Sucessor 
            root._rightNode = deleteNode(root._rightNode, root._data);
        }

        return root;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Function to find smallest element in the left subtree
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="root"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Node inOrderSucessor(Node inOrder)
    {
        // Loop runs till leaf node
        while (inOrder._leftNode != null)
        {
            inOrder = inOrder._leftNode;
        }

        return inOrder;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Function to call searchTree() function 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data"></param> String which is to be searched
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string search(string data)
    {
        Node result = searchTree(root, data);

        // Data does not exist int the tree
        if (result == null)
        {
            return "Not Found";
        }

        return result._data;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Private recursive function to search for a particular node in a tree  
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="root"></param> Root of the tree
    /// <param name="data"></param> String which is to be searched
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Node searchTree(Node root, string data)
    {
        // Base Case: root is null
        // or data stored at root is equal to string which is to be searched 
        if (root == null || string.Compare(root._data, data) == 0)
        {
            return root;
        }

        // -- Recursively moving down the tree --
        // Data stored at root is smaller than the string which is to be searched 
        if (string.Compare(root._data, data) < 0)
        {
            return searchTree(root._rightNode, data);
        }
        // Data stored at root is greater than the string which is to be searched 
        else
        {
            return searchTree(root._leftNode, data);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Function to call private inOrder() function 
    /// </summary>
    public void inOrder()
    {
        inOrder(root);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// -- In-Order traversal --
    /// Traverse left subtree recursively
    /// Visite root node
    /// traverse right subtree resursively
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="root"></param>
    private void inOrder(Node root)
    {
        if (root != null)
        {
            inOrder(root._leftNode);
            Console.WriteLine(root._data);
            inOrder(root._rightNode);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Function to call private preOrder() function 
    /// </summary>
    public void preOrder()
    {
        preOrder(root);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// -- Pre-Order Traverse --
    /// Visit root node
    /// Traverse left subtree recursively
    /// Traverse right subtree resursively 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="root"></param>
    private void preOrder(Node root)
    {
        if (root != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(root._data);
            preOrder(root._leftNode);
            preOrder(root._rightNode);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Function to call private postOrder() function 
    /// </summary>
    public void postOrder()
    {
        postOrder(root);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// -- Post-Order Traversal -- 
    /// Traverse left subtree recursively
    /// Traverse right subtree recursively
    /// Visite root node
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="root"></param>
    private void postOrder(Node root)
    {
        if (root != null)
        {
            postOrder(root._leftNode);
            postOrder(root._rightNode);
            Console.WriteLine(root._data);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Printing level order traversal using iterative approach
    /// Referenced from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-level-order-traversal-line-line/
    /// </summary>
    public void printTree()
    {
        // Base Case 
        // Tree is empty
        if (root == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Empty queue for level
        Queue<Node> queue = new Queue<Node>();

        queue.Enqueue(root);

        while (true)
        {
            int nodeCount = queue.Count;    //number of nodes at current level
            if (nodeCount == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            while (nodeCount > 0)
            {
                Node node = queue.Peek();
                Console.Write(node._data + " ");
                queue.Dequeue();
                if (node._leftNode != null)
                {
                    queue.Enqueue(node._leftNode);
                }
                if (node._rightNode != null)
                {
                    queue.Enqueue(node._rightNode);
                }
                nodeCount--;
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Creating an instance of BinaryStringSearchTree class
        BinaryStringSearchTree tree = new BinaryStringSearchTree();

        // Inserting element
        tree.insert("Karen");
        tree.insert("Bob");
        tree.insert("Tom");

        // Print tree
        Console.WriteLine("Printing tree");
        tree.printTree();
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For any node:

1. Everything in the left branch is alphabetically ordered < the current node.
2. Everything in the right branch is alphabetically ordered > the current node.

This provides a couple of unique properties

1. You can find any node by simplying going left or right based on whether the key you are searching is lexicographically < or > than the current node.  You will either arrive at the destination, or a non-matching leaf node (in which case the key doesn't exist), and in `O(Log n)` time.
2. An in-order traversal gives all the keys in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

In your example,  they meant the order of the first symbol in each name.

If you see, the name order from left to right, is from the first character in ABC to the last.

Also, there is a special case with the second occurrence of Karen name - 
The default behavior in this tree, if same data entered, is "move right", then Karen compared to Tom -> K is "smaller" the T, so it gets left from it.

In any case, here is better example, from it you can see the order numbers in binary tree:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4647/A-simple-binary-tree-implementation-with-VB-NET

Answer (score -1):

I think this article bellow will be very helpful for you on understanding the concepts of binary tree, it also provides common code samples in C/C++ and Java:

http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html